# Dropdown unordered list for mobile view

Tags: html, css

i've never made a website before so i'm kind of winging it. i'm using html+css+java and i haven't had a problem until now and i'm kind of stumped.

i have this menu for my desktop view (http://puu.sh/H6daI/f9c757571f.png) which functions exactly as i want it to. however in mobile view (http://puu.sh/H6dba/27b97bc952.png), i'd like everything under "categories" to collapse and use the pointer to expand the contents.

i don't really know how to go about this and i'm not finding much help online. i'd imagine i'd have to incorporate javascript like i did for the sidebar nav in mobile view, but it's not coming together.

here's my html and css, if that helps any

```
<div class="sidemenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="init" > <embed src="images/pointer.svg" style="width: 100%;" ></embed></li>
        <li><a  style="font-weight: 500; pointer-events:none; font-size: 16px">Categories</a></li>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <li><a  href="shop.html" >All Sets</a></li>
        <li><a  href="featured.html" >Featured Sets</a></li>
        <li><a  href="popular.html" >Popular Sets</a></li>
        
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.init {
    width: 2.5%;
   
}

  .sidemenu ul li.active a, .sidemenu ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:rgb(82, 82, 82);
    background:#ffcccc no-repeat center top;
}

  .sidemenu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 950px) {

.line {
        border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgb(58, 58, 58);
        display: block;
        
        width: 140px;
        margin-left: 46px;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    .sidemenu a {
        text-decoration:none;
        color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
        margin: 48px;
        line-height: 48px;
        font-weight: 400;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add the "display: none" property to everything that you'd like to collapse in the css media query. i recommend putting the menu list in a div tag. That way you'll only have to hide the div tag.

Then in javascript you can use the click event on the Categories. When a user clicks the categories, "display: block" property gets added to to the menu list.

Heres some javascript that you can use:

```
// First get the categories element from html
const categories = document.getElementById('categories');

// Keep track if the menu is opened or not
let menuOpen = false;

// Also get the menu list that you should put in a div tag
const menuList = document.getElementById('menuList');

// Add event to th categories
categories.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // check is the menu is open or not

    if(!menuOpen) {
        // Its not opened than add display block to menu list
        menuList.style.display = 'block'

        // Change menuOpen to true
        menuOpen = true

    } else {
        // Menu is already open

        menuList.style.display = 'none'

        // Change menuOpen to false
        menuOpen = false
    }

});
```

I assume that you want to add some transitions to the menu list to make it look nice. I recommend using the transition css property.

Comment: so the menu list in the div tag like this? `<ul>
        <li class="init" > <embed src="images/pointer.svg" style="width: 100%;" ></embed></li>
        <li><a  style="font-weight: 500; pointer-events:none; font-size: 16px">Categories</a></li>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <div class="menulist" id="menulist">
        <li><a  href="shop.html" >All Sets</a></li>
        <li><a  href="featured.html" >Featured Sets</a></li>
        <li><a  href="popular.html" >Popular Sets</a></li>
        
       </li>
    </div>
    </ul>`

where does id="categories" go?

Comment: yes using the div like that will make it easier to select the list in css and javascript. You should put the id like this: ```< li  id="categories" ><a  style="font-weight: 500; pointer-events:none; font-size: 16px">Categories</a></li>```  since you have "pointer-events:none" in the a tag, then a click will occur on the li tag.

Comment: ok that's what i thought. the list is collapsed and all that is visible is the text "categories" and the arrow. in css is set "cursor: pointer" on the arrow, but nothing is happening when i click on it and there is nothing else clickable. i may be missing something? thanks for the help so far, i'm getting somewhere at least.

edit: i took out "pointer events: none" and the categories text becomes clickable to expand the list, but i want the arrow to do it.

Comment: ok i got it working in mobile now! but when i switch to desktop view all the contents of class=menuList disappears. is there something in js i can set to make it so that it just displays the content of the list regardless in desktop view? i only want it to be able to toggle in mobile.

Comment: Ok, if you want just the arrow to do it then add the id="categories" to the arrows Li tag. Make sue to add `pointer-events:"none"` to the embed tag. That way click will happen on the Li tag only. If you want the list to collapse for both the arrow and the categories text. Then put both of them in a div tag and add the id to that div container. you can change name of the id if you want according to the tag, but also change it in the javascript.

Comment: if you remove the arrow from desktop view and add the click event to the arrow only Then it should work fine. Also, make sure that you are hiding the menu only in the mobile media query. You may have to refresh the page once in the browser view for the menuList to reaper.